# Extract a substring from a file if two character positions from another file are present within the substring, when line ID matches

Tags: awk

I have a file with an identifier (ID) and two positional numbers. In the real file there are 12 columns and the positions in question are found in field 7 and 8, however for the sake of clarity I removed that information from this example file1:

```
ID1   1   18
ID2   5   12
ID3   9   24
ID2   7   14
```

The second file contains strings I am interested in. Lines have identification as in file1. file2:

```
ID1   abcdefghijklmnopqr*stuvw**xyz
ID2   ab*cdefghijklmno*pqrst*uvwxyz
ID3   *abcd*efghi*jklmnopqrs*tuvwxyz
ID4   abcde*fgh*ijklmnopq*rstuvwxyz*
```

At such, the string in field 2 is in itself separated by asterisks (*) into smaller substrings. In this case, a substring is defined as any string between start of the field and an asterisk, between two asterisks, between asterisk and end of field or between start/end of field.

What I want to do is, if ID matches between files and both positions from file1 correspond to characters that are present in the same substring in file2, append the whole substring to file1, excluding the asterisk. Desired output:

```
ID1   1   18   abcdefghijklmnopqr
ID2   5   12   cdefghijklmno
ID3   9   24   
ID2   7   14   cdefghijklmno
```

Explanation:

- For ID1, position 1 in the string corresponds to "a" which is also the first letter of the substring. Position 18 corresponds to "r" which is also the last letter of the substring, an thus printing position 1-18 is adequate.
- For the first occurance of ID2 however, position 5 in the string corresponds to d, which is not the first letter of the substring. Neither is position 12 the last letter of the substring (k is in position 12). Still, the whole substring (c through o) should be printed.
- For ID3, positions 9 and 24 are in different substrings, thus no substring should be printed.
- For the second occurance of ID2 the same is true as in the first occurance, this example was provided to show how an ID can occur several times.

The strings can start and/or end with an asterisk, more than one subsequent asterisk can occur, and strings can also be completely void of asterisks. There are IDs in file2 that do not occur in file1. File1 can contain more than one line per ID, file2 only contains one line per ID.

I hope I made my problem clear. I am still very new to this, and thankful of any help.

Comment: Very good beginner Q and you did your own formatting!

Comment: read up on `awk`'s `match()` and `substr()` functions. Good luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$ cat tst.awk
NR==FNR {
    beg[$1] = $2
    end[$1] = $3
    next
}
{
    str = ""
    tgt = substr($2,beg[$1],end[$1]-beg[$1])
    if ( tgt !~ /[*]/ ) {
        bef = substr($2,1,beg[$1]-1)
        aft = substr($2,end[$1]+1)
        sub(/.*[*]/,"",bef)
        sub(/[*].*/,"",aft)
        str = bef tgt aft
    }
    print $1, beg[$1], end[$1], str
}

$ awk -f tst.awk file1 file2
ID1 1 18 abcdefghijklmnopq
ID2 5 12 cdefghijlmno
ID3 9 24
```

---

Given your updated example:

```
$ cat tst.awk
NR==FNR {
    map[$1] = $2
    next
}
{
    val = map[$1]
    beg = $2
    end = $3
    str = ""
    tgt = substr(val,beg,end-beg)
    if ( tgt !~ /[*]/ ) {
        bef = substr(val,1,beg-1)
        aft = substr(val,end+1)
        sub(/.*[*]/,"",bef)
        sub(/[*].*/,"",aft)
        str = bef tgt aft
    }
    print $1, beg, end, str
}

$ awk -f tst.awk file2 file1
ID1 1 18 abcdefghijklmnopq
ID2 5 12 cdefghijlmno
ID3 9 24
ID2 7 14 cdefghijklno
```

Comment: Hey, thank you Ed. This worked for the example I originally provided, however when adapted to my files the script did not properly match IDs and thus gave the wrong output. I also realised I had not explained my problem properly and given all parameters, I am sorry for this and thankful for your time and knowledge. I edited my question.